# xPages typeahead is slow for external data source

Tags: javascript, java, xpages

Here is my simple edit box control with typeAhead enabled:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputNameEditBox">
    <xp:typeAhead mode="full" minChars="3" ignoreCase="true"
        valueList="#{javascript:return typeAheadList();}"
        var="searchValue" valueMarkup="true" id="typeAhead1">
    </xp:typeAhead>
</xp:inputText>
```

And here is SSJS founction call for typeAhead:

```
var v=new typeAheadTools.personLookup();
function typeAheadList(){
    var personsList = v.getPersonsList(searchValue);
    var returnList = "<ul>";

    if(personsList.length>0){
        for (var i=0; i<personsList.length; i++) { 
            returnList += ["<li>",personsList[i],"</li>"].join("");
        }       
    } else {
        returnList += ["<li>","None found","</li>"].join("");
    }

    returnList += "</ul>"; 
    return returnList;  
}
```

The problem is that I pull list of users by using external Java API and it's very slow:

```
package typeAheadTools;
public class personLookup {
    public ArrayList<String> getPersonsList(String searchString) throws IOException {
        URL url = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        ArrayList<String> personsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            url = new URL("http://aaaa.bbbb.com/DirectoryAPI/abc?person=" + searchString);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setReadTimeout(300 * 1000);
            connection.connect();

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                personsList.add(inputLine.trim());
            }
            in.close(); 
            url = null;
            return personsList;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return personsList;

        } finally {
            url = null;

            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
                in = null;
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
                connection = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The API may return either plain text or JSON. But the key question - is there any other approach I can parse that URL output for typeAhead function. Is REST Service the right control to use instead of Java bean?

Comment: Type ahead can't be faster than that API. Unless you fetch and cache all the data (not recommended for large sets). You can try to call API directly in clientside JS - initialize Dojo/JQuery that way.